# How to edit file name in file inspector?

Tags: xcode

There are multiple discussions on how to programmatically edit a file name in the file inspector.  However, if I simply want to manually change the name of this file in the file navigator.

I have tried clicking on it, then waiting, then clicking again.  That seems to work sometimes, but with this xib file I can't seem to get it to work.

This seems to happen intermittently, so I can't provide repeatable steps.  I'm looking for an alternative to clicking, waiting, then clicking again guaranteed way to rename a file in the Toolbar/File Navigator.

[image]

Comment: Select + Enter? But the File Inspector isn't enough for you: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYuMx.jpg ?

Comment: @Larme, thank you.  That answers my question if you want to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in `Finder.app`:
Select the file, tap <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Or using the File Inspector (right panel):
Select the file, `View/Inspector/File`, change the name there.

[Like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYuMx.jpg)